# Change kubernetes default registry to registry.k8s.io

Tags: kubernetes

I have a k8s cluster deployed with kubeadm and its current version is v1.21 and use docker as CRI
I want to upgrade it to v1.25, so I was reading the release notes, and I read about the new k8s registry, which is `registry.k8s.io` in its release notes [there](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.25.md#no-really-you-must-read-this-before-you-upgrade) in the last paragraph but I don't know how to check what my current registry is and how to change the default registry to the new one?

I found this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2671) about this change, but I can't find my answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check your current registry run the below command

```
kubeadm config images list
```

Output will be the images list where you can find the current registry.

To change the registry to `registry.k8s.io` you can use the [kubeadm init command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/).

```
Kubeadm init –image-repository= registry.k8s.io
```

Restart the cluster after changing the image as the configuration will be updated correctly,Then run `kubeadm upgrade v1.25` to update your cluster.Now the clusters will be upgraded and will use the new registry.

After that you can use `kubeadm config images pull` command to pull the images from the new registry, also make sure to update any existing deployments.

Answer (score 0):

You can check a current registry by checking images of Kubernetes components you have now in your cluster. That is just a source of from where to get images for components like scheduler etc.

But there is nothing to care about, you should not be affected by that change anyhow.